# how to save the automatically generated "div id " . i am trying to save the div id which is visible on screen when user scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to save the automatically  generated "div id "  which is visible  on screen when user scroll... and jump back to the saved div id..when user reloadsloads the page.

i am able to generate the id's dynamically with the following code

```
generateid: function() {
  $("#generate br ~ br").each(function(index, element) {

    $(this).after("<div id=\"bookmark-" + index + "\"></div>");

  });

},
```

and trying to scroll the save the id ,but unable achieve ..the code looks as follow

```
check: function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $("div[id^='bookmark-']").each(function(index, element) {
      if ($(this).is(":visible"), $(window)) {

        console.log($(this).attr('id') + " is visible");

      } else {

      }
    });
  });
},
```

but statically able to pass the id and scroll to the div.with the following code

```
scroll: function() {
  var container = $('div'),
    scrollTo = $('#bookmark-65');

  container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()

  });

},
```

Comment: where are you saving your bookmark? when you reload, is it still there?

Comment: i an unable to save bookmark.

Comment: Hi there, you could save your id element on scroll with sessionStorage or cookie Storage and then recall it on reload

Comment: yeah i know how to implement with session ,local ,cookie  storage , but my requirement is to store with the "div id"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save current scroll position, it does not have to be a `div`. You can just save scroll position to cookies.

Example:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
  return "";
}
```

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: yeah i know how to implement with session ,local ,cookie storage , but my requirement is to store with the "div id"

Comment: Reloading deletes all your generated `div`s. You need to save the state somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try the star-Operator: `$("div[id*='bookmark-']")`

Comment: Could you add an explanation what the tilde operator does?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant the star  `*` ... This works fine for the Problem: `$("div[id*='bookmark-']").each(... `